# Setting Data context

Tags: c#, json, data-binding, windows-8, datacontext

I have faced a next problem:

I have a JSON file coming from server with some data. And i have written a class, that allows me to deserialize the JSON:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int? version { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool? isNeeded { get; set; }

    //protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    //{
    //    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    //    if (handler != null)
    //    {
    //        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    //    }
    //}
}
```

And i have a custom control which i set the DataContext to Person - binding works, but i want to control to react when some fields ( 1 or many ) are modified.

**1) Do i have to write PropertyChanged to each property?**

I have managed to write this:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int? version { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }
    public bool? isNeeded { get; set; }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string _name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_name));
        }
    }
}
```

But question is should i create private variable for each property and should i write EventChanged for each property? Or there is a simplier way?

Comment: What error message do you get when it fails?

Comment: I have managed to win this battle, i added private variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string _name;
private int? _version;
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public int? version 
    {
        get { return _version; }
        set { SetField(ref _version, value, "version"); }
    }
public int? id { get; set; }
public string name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetField(ref _name, value, "name"); }

    }
public bool? isNeeded { get; set; }

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

}
```